# App Generator on Android

Tags: android

I want to develop an app which will create another Android app as output.

So my question is, whether this thing is possible in Android?

I got one PC software called "App Inventor" which takes data from user and give .apk file as

output,which can be installed in Android device.

This same thing my app should do on Android device.

Can any one give any ideas regarding this?

Comment: You can't, but you can perhaps create the source code.. send it to a remote server that will create the apk, and get it from there.. not easy though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is, whether this thing is possible in Android?

An Android app can generate text files. These text files may represent Java source code, layout XML, etc. However, an Android app cannot run a Java compiler or the Android tool chain.